# Inserts at wrong position - why does lua table behave this way?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I needed to add elements to a lua table in a certain order and tried to insert each element to its final position (but in a random order). I'm new to lua and hadn't worked with table.insert before (only read that tables support both an associative and an array form), but I was pretty sure it couldn't work this way, so I made a little test:

```lua
local test = {}
table.insert(test, 5, "5")
table.insert(test, 1, "1")
table.insert(test, 4, "4")
table.insert(test, 3, "3")
table.insert(test, 2, "2")
```

Test output after each insert delivered this interesting behavior:

```lua
["5"]
["5","1"]
["1","4","5"]
["1","3","4","5"]
["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

Actually it worked better than expected (I thought that inserting to a table with two elements at position 4 would probably append), but the lines 2 and 3 got me absolutely confused. Inserting at position 1 appends, and the next insert reorders the other elements?!?

Next try was to avoid table.insert and instead use test[5] = "5" etc.
The result was exactly the same...

Only way to fix it was to initialize elements 1 through 5 with an empty string first, and then inserting the actual values in random order.

Does anybody have an idea why the tables behave this way?

Comment: I get `bad argument #2 to 'insert' (position out of bounds)` at line 2.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Different lua version maybe? Looks like I'm using Lua 5.1

Comment: Yes, that message is output by Lua 5.2+.

Comment: Anyway, `test[5] = "5"` is the simplest and best approach.

Comment: Okay, then I should probably file that behavior under "bug"! ;)

Comment: Yes, but as I said that also only seems to work safely when test[1] through test[4] already exist.

Comment: My 5 outputs on Lua 5.1 are: `{[5]="5"}, {[1]="1", [5]="5"}, {[1]="1", [4]="4", [5]="5"}, {[1]="1", [3]="3", [4]="4", [5]="5"}, {[1]="1", [2]="2", [4]="3", [5]="4", [6]="5"}`

Comment: What @EgorSkriptunoff is saying is that your debug output is formatted in a way which misleads you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operations do not apply sensibly a table without a [sequence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7). The first statement creates a table without a sequence. Then it all goes south.

[6.6 – Table Manipulation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.6)

> Remember that, whenever an operation needs the length of a table, all caveats about the length operator apply (see [§3.4.7](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7)).

One generally chooses to maintain the sequence of a table or not. If not, avoid functions and the # operator (it's built-in implementation) that are designed for sequences.

You could build up the table as @lhf describes:

```
local test = {}
test[5] = "5"
test[1] = "1"
test[4] = "4"
test[3] = "3"
test[2] = "2"
```

and then at a point when you are convinced that you have created a table with a sequence, begin treating the table as such.

Comment: Thank you, Tom! The paragraph about table borders finally dissolved my confusion.